# Error when creating a user by joining several tables ionic-angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm trying to register a user and at the same time, assign his role to make it look good, at the moment of creating the user it works perfectly, but at the moment of adding his role I get an error

**error: "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'status' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `profiles`**

code

```
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {
    // @Input() rol: Rol;
    public form: FormGroup;
    public usuario: Usuario = new Usuario();
    public perfil: Perfil = new Perfil();
    public rol: Rol;
    public id_rol: number;
    constructor(
        public route: ActivatedRoute,
        public usuarioService: UsuarioService,
        public perfilService: PerfilService,
        public router: Router
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.form = new FormGroup({
            name: new FormControl('', [
                Validators.required,
                Validators.minLength(3),
            ]),
            apellidos: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
            edad: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
            email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
            rol: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
        });
    }

    onSave() {
        // Crear usuario
        this.usuario.name = this.form.get('name').value;
        this.usuario.apellidos = this.form.get('apellidos').value;
        this.usuario.password = '123456';
        this.usuario.edad = this.form.get('edad').value;
        this.usuario.email = this.form.get('email').value;
        this.usuario.status = 'activo';
        this.id_rol = this.form.get('rol').value;
        // seleccionar rol
        this.rol = new Rol();
        this.rol.id = this.id_rol;
        // Crear perfil
        this.perfil.status = 'activo';
        this.perfil.usuario = this.usuario;
        this.perfil.rol = this.rol;

        this.usuarioService.create(this.usuario).subscribe((res) => {
            this.perfilService.create(this.perfil).subscribe((res) => {
            console.log('Creado...');
            this.router.navigate(['/admin']);
        })}),(error) => {
                console.log(error);
        };
    }
}
```

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong for this error to appear, it only appears when creating the profile that the table that joins user with role, apirest is created with laravel

data base

[image]

network
[image]

code profile

```
Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('status');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('rol_id')->unsigned();

            #referencia de rol
            $table->foreign('rol_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('rols');

            #referencia de usuario
            $table->foreign('user_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('users')
                ->onDelete('cascade');


            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

model profile

```
class profile extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['profiles'];

    //Primero se crea un modelo para obetner los datos que estan relacionados con la tabla profile con usaurio y rol
    public function Usuario() {
        return $this->belongsTo(user::class, 'user_id');
    }
    public function Rol() {
        return $this->belongsTo(rol::class, 'rol_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show code in Back-end and Network on browser. Maybe you miss `status` field when create or you should `default value of status` on migrate

Comment: I have already added what I think is necessary, let me know if you need more.

Comment: `$table->string('status')->nullable()` you try  `nullable` to `status` field

Comment: The error is still displayed

Comment: https://www.linkedin.com/in/linh-nguyen-96919a143/ you connect to me. I will help you

Comment: I have already sent you the invitation